# Python gamepad input?

Tags: python, joystick

Is there any good alternative to pygame for gamepad input?
Crossplatform would be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's gamepad support in [`myro`](http://wiki.roboteducation.org/Myro_Reference_Manual#Gamepad). I've dealt with the robotic functionality of the library, but not directly with the gamepad stuff. My encounters and the documentation indicate that `myro` is supported on windows, mac, and linux distributions.

Comment: I voted up but `myro` uses pygame. I went to see the source just to find out how was `myro` managing joystick devices, and I found the source a [call for pygame.event.pump()](http://svn.cs.brynmawr.edu/viewvc/Myro/trunk/myro/__init__.py?view=markup). I can't now downvote, but take into account that `myro` is using pygame.

Comment: One thing to mention, in the same source it's commented that no gamepad support for Mac at line `198` from the above link.